# Best way to import XML hierarchical data into Sql Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a web application written in ASP.NET C# application where user can upload his data in an XML form.  This data has one-to many relationship. This is the reason I choose XML over CSV. If there is a way to do this with CSV pleas give a hint. It is much less verbose.
My XML has following structure:

```
<Parent column1="value1" column2="value2">
    <Child column1="value3" />
    <Child column1="value4" />
</Parent>
```

This template repeats itself. When I get the uploaded file it is in a form of byte array (byte[]). How can I elegantly import that in the two corresponding tables, Parent and Child?
Bear in mind that I will host this web app, so I probably will not have acces to command line tools or rights to run xp_cmdshell.
My idea for now is to create System.XmlDocument and then traverse that document and insert rows via stored procedures. For each row in each table one statement.
What I am asking is: Is there a better way?

Comment: will the user have to create his/her own xml file manually or will you provide a software to create it or do you just don't care how they will create that xml?

Comment: do you care about the XML sizes? if you do, how many items will the user send? these are all informations that you need to know before chosing what kind of technology to use, then people will be able to suggest too

Comment: @Robson Filho Colodeti - I guess they will create it via export from their database or spreadsheet. I know it would be easier for them to use CSV if only there were not this one-to-many relation. Size is another issue as weel. It will range from a few rows to about 10000 Parent, with each up to about 50 children

Comment: well, some1 has to decide how the format will be, lol, you or them. We cannot suggest you a "better" way if you don't have that defined =)

Comment: The format is described in the question.

Comment: how often will the users send the xml files? daily? weekly? monthly? more than one time a day?

Comment: Once a week for larger files. Perhaps daily for smaller. But for smaller data I already have a web interface.

Comment: i think the problem here is not "how you will handle the data in the web server" but how the user will create the XML files. are you able to create a desktop application for them to create these files? and maybe make the application connect to a web service directly... what you think about this?

Comment: You rae not getting the poibt. Please read the question again and if you do not understand it try again.

Comment: probably i'm not getting it right then =) asking "is there a better way" made me think that you needed a help on the whole process, but i guess then that you just need help with the XML parsing to SQL, right?

Comment: Well yes. As it is now i will parse XML on C# side with XmlDocument and call stored procedures for inserts. But I would like to know if there is a way to send XML as a whole to sql server and let it parse it self. Via some definition of course. Similiar as using FOR XML clause for queris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at SQLXML Bulk Load which is optimized for importing large xml files. I've used this successfully in the past with thousands of records and beats other xml imports hands down.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms171878.aspx

Comment: Thank you. This seems interesting. I took a look at example at link you provided and this would be useful if not for primary and foreign keys issue. In my database tables I use identity with autoincrement. Yet the example shows that primary and foreign keys are provided in XML file. This is incompatible. The relationship is visible from XML structure. And I cannot request users to provide keys in my database which they do not know.

Comment: You don't need to define the primary keys in the xml. If you database tables have an identity column then I'm use that the SQLXML bulk load can accomodate this. You just need to poke around the documentation and find an example based on an identity column. Could you please mark this as answered if you are happy with my suggestion?

Comment: I have accepted and upvoted this answer because it was in right direction for my question. I did not use it though and instead I usex XmlReader. The reasong being I needed to do some validation involving comparing different attributes inside a node I didn't know how to define XSD for such validation. But for importing data that is correct your proposition is OK. I would use it if I could.

Comment: Thanks very much for the upvote. It may not have helped you in this scenario, but it is a handy tool to keep around and maybe someone else will benefit from the answer :)